# Disable cipher suites on Jetty server within Spark

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, jetty, spark-java

I would like to disable cipher suites (list below) deemed weak by SSL Labs to pass their SSL test on a SparkJava server.

Ciphers to disable:
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

Spark version spark-core 2.5 (includes Jetty 9.3), Java 8.

There are no external configuration files for Spark and no mention in the documentation on how to do this properly without messing things up.

Could someone with the know-how please explain exactly what to do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Sun JVM without any additional security providers, then Spark is using the JVM's Sun security provider for SSL/TLS - JSSE. You can disable specific algorithms by modifying [JSSE's configuration file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#DisabledAlgorithms) located at `jre/lib/security/java.security`.

Specifically you could do something like this:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

The above describes how to disable cipher suites at the Java VM level - you can also [configure this within Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html#configuring-sslcontextfactory-cipherSuites). This can be done in code using [SslContext.setExcludeCipherSuites(java.lang.String…​)](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.html#setExcludeCipherSuites-java.lang.String...-).

It can also be configured in XML. Create a new configuration file `${jetty.base}/etc/disable-ciphers.xml` (it can have any name as long as it does not start with `jetty-`)

```
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
      "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
  <Call name="addExcludeCipherSuites">
    <Arg>
      <Array type="String">
        <Item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_.*$/Item>
        <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</Item>
      </Array>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

Finally, you need to tell Jetty about this file, so modify `${jetty.base}/start.ini` by adding a relative path reference to `disable-ciphers.xml` to the tail of the file.

However, Spark does not allow configuration of Jetty - see Github [#314](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/314) - which means this approach cannot work unless you instantiate Jetty manually as discussed in the comments to the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I cannot find the tls package in jdk - is it possible it's not included or cannot be accessed or am I just blind? jdk. yields 5 packages in my Spark project.

Comment: No worries, @WonderfulWorld. [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) is the correct name for SSL, and provides the encryption for HTTPS. TLS itself is implemented in the [JSSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Secure_Socket_Extension). The configuration point to switch off the algorithms is a file, `jre/lib/security/java.security`, which needs to be modified. I've updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: I see thanks, now it's clear. Is there a way to achieve the same effect without globally overriding the configuration? The project I'm delivering is completely self-contained, requiring only a default JRE 8 installation - it's essentially one .jar file (with embedded database, etc.) and a couple of config files plus a script to start it. So a distributable config file in its own directory would be exactly to spec (if this is possible..?). Sorry for all the requests for more details...

Comment: I'm unaware of how you could do this just for your app, unless you package your own JVM. Just a thought though - if you're running the SSL Labs scan, I assume that your customers require a high level of security (military? government?). If so, it would be *good* to offer to modify the whole JVM setup. If your customers are the general public, then you probably don't need this level of security. But you could still offer to modify their configuration in the install. I can't see any bad side effects except in very weird environments with legacy (insecure) apps.

Comment: Thanks. If there's really no other way, I'll suggest the modification. I agree it will likely be beneficial with no side effects, but as the environment is largely out of my hands, just the fact that it's a "change" will lift some eyebrows unfortunately. Anyway thanks very much again for your help.

Comment: Andrew, sorry to bring this up again - I just had a chance to test this and it did not solve the problem. I kept the old disabled algorithms and added the ones you suggested, resulting in: jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 2048, 3DES, AES keySize <= 128. I am positive that it it written in the correct place, as taking out SSLv3 resulted in a big drop in evaluation on SSL Labs. However, the weak Diffie-Hellman (DH) key exchange parameters are still available according to the test. Is it possible something was left out?

Comment: @WonderfulWorld - I was wrong - keySize <= 128 _does not work_ with the symmetric encryption algorithms. I am very sorry about that. After some experimentation, the only was I found to eliminate the ciphers is by specifically naming them. I believe the 3DES statement does work though because you want to eliminate this totally, regardless of keySize. I have corrected my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @WonderfulWorld: I think I found the solution to configure this at the Jetty level - do take a look above

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the followup, I tried it and it did eliminate the weak AES suites, but not the 3DES one. Maybe I found the reason: java's internal name for cipher suites may be different than the official name: a list can be found under "Standard Algorithm Name Documentation". After some testing, adding this to jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms removed the 3DES suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA. However I much prefer your idea on setting up a Jetty config file (as it may even make it possible to enable 256 bit suites for extra brownie points, which are disabled by default). Continued ->

Comment: Continued <-: Unforunately as Jetty is embedded in Spark, there is no start.ini file and printing the property jetty.base returns null. This may of course be trivial, but I don't yet know how to do it.

Comment: You can use the API call approach I mentioned - that does not require a config file change

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this - I tried that too, but couldn't get the SslContextFactory instance used by the server to call the method you mentioned. It's not a singleton and I can only create a new instance of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114293/discussion-between-andrew-alcock-and-wonderfulworld).

Comment: It seems to work with Jetty 11 too by the way: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/jetty-11/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.html#addExcludeCipherSuites(java.lang.String...)